# If I owe the IRS, how can I protect my new business?

Tags: irs, business

I want to fix and flip some houses, and potentially pay the IRS once I make some money, but I don't want them putting liens on my properties before I can sell them.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate here. If the intent of flipping the properties is to repay your tax debts a lien just means that they would be entitled to some of the proceeds from the sale, which was your intention anyway.

Comment: "*and **potentially** pay the IRS*" or potentially not pay them...

Comment: @JohnFx A lien can have a big effect on your ability to sell a property, or borrow money against it.

Answer (score 5):

Owing the IRS is a bad situation to be in. They have powers that no other creditor has, and usually will take any steps to get their money.

However they can also take the long view, and can be negotiated with. Your best bet under these circumstances is to negotiate a payment schedule with them, so that you can pay off your debt over time. If you do that and stick to the payments, they are unlikely to put leins on anything, or otherwise interfere with your business.